# Why put well-voted question on hold long after accepted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why has [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7429/where-do-i-get-the-standard-tiny-facebook-and-twitter-icons) just been put on hold? It's still a valid question and the accepted answer is still useful.

This isn't my own question, but I have come across it and found it quite helpful. It seems a bit odd that 2.5 years after the fact it's being closed down, especially when both the question & answer both have several up-votes....

Comment: Sometimes fish slip though the net but sooner or later they get caught, basically the question even though helpful may not be suitable... But to add and something @John taught me when I was newly born here - is that great answers don't get deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is looking for a list of resources which is offtopic at this site. They attract spam and other low quality answers. This question is no different although you need to be a mod to see the deleted answers).

But just because it is on hold doesn't mean it will be deleted. The answers are still accessible to everyone. Just no new answers can be added.